# Need help using the material-datetime-picker module in an Aurelia-CLi based project

Tags: datetimepicker, aurelia

I'm trying to use the [material-datetime-picker](https://github.com/ripjar/material-datetime-picker) in my [Aurelia-CLI](https://github.com/aurelia/cli) project.

I have added the dependency in my `aurelia.json` like this :

```
{
    "name": "material-datetime-picker",
    "path": "../node_modules/material-datetime-picker/dist/js",
    "main": "datepicker"
}
```

The bundling is done without any error.

I'm able to do `import MaterialDateTimePicker from 'material-datetime-picker';`

But the error occur when I'm trying to instanciate a new object : `const picker = new MaterialDateTimePicker();`

I get this error : `TypeError: _materialDatetimePicker2.default is not a constructor`

I have post an issue asking for help to integrate this module in my project on the github repo [here](https://github.com/ripjar/material-datetime-picker/issues/90)

I'm not sure if this is a bug of the module or a problem of integration in my project.

Comment: Sometimes adding libraries/dependencies are funky with Aurelia. Not sure if this will fix your problem, but it's worth trying to change your import to "import "material-datetime-picker" or "import * as MaterialDateTimePicker() from "material-datetime-picker"

Comment: Thanks. If I do `import * as MaterialDateTimePicker from "material-datetime-picker";` I get `MaterialDateTimePicker` as undefined. If I add the `()` the transpiler cannot transpile my code. `import "material-datetime-picker"` doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to put MaterialDateTimePicker(). Remove the parenthesis and see if it works.

Comment: If you look good my comment, I already do it without the parenthesis and it is still undefined.

Comment: Not sure. I thought that would fix it :(

Comment: From the looks of datepicker.js, it isn't an AMD file but a CommonJS file build with browserify. Aurelia CLI expects AMD type modules, because it's using requirejs internally. So this won't work, unfortunately.

Maybe it could be solved by also transpiling the material-datetime-picker source directly to AMD but I've tried that and failed. Anyway, leaving this here as an idea. :)